# Variance= Expected Value

Tags: probability

Is there is any intuitive explanation what does it mean when Variance$=$Expected Value? or there is no connection else from them having the same value?

Comment: @Chinny84 Just shift and scale a standard normal distributed rv.

Comment: @StefanHansen et al. Thanks guys. I totally misread the equations. I was thinking given a set of numbers when will the variance be equal to the mean. I will remove

Comment: nothing special. The Poisson distribution always has this feature. And you can construct such a case from most distributions with  at least two parameters.

Comment: I would say there is no connection. Every random variable $X$ with finite second moment induces a (unique) random variable $Y:=X-\mu+\sigma^2$ that satisfies the equality: $\mathbb EY=\text{Var}Y$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the expected value and the variance are not intrinsically related. For a normal distribution for example, the variance can be set independently of the expected value.

There are specific distributions where the variance is dependent on the expected value. Consider for instance a random variable $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, where $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}(X) = \operatorname{\mathbb{Var}}(X) = \lambda$. In this case, the expected value and the variance are inherently related.

Concluding, it really depends on the distribution and the number of parameters that you can change whether the variance and expected value are related or even possibly equal by definition.